# Apollo on local client doesn't trigger the local resolvers

Tags: graphql, apollo

Apollo doesn't trigger the resolvers in the case of Local state Client (frontent local state). Apollo 2.7

Does anyone have any idea why it happens?

Here is the setup:

Apollo client

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

import { resolvers, typeDefs } from './resolvers';
import { initCache } from './init-cache';

export default function createApolloClient(initialState, ctx) {
  // The `ctx` (NextPageContext) will only be present on the server.
  // use it to extract auth headers (ctx.req) or similar.
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: Boolean(ctx),
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/cixmkt2ul01q00122mksg82pn', // Server URL (must be absolute)
      credentials: 'include', // Additional fetch() options like `credentials` or `headers`
      fetch,
    }),
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    connectToDevTools: true,
    cache: initCache({
                   robot: {
                     __typename: 'Robot',
                     name: 'Robbie',
                     status: 'live',
                    },

                  member: {
                     __typename: 'Member',
                     name: 'RFesagfd',
                     }
                   }),
     })
  }
```

Types & resolvers (resolvers.js)

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const typeDefs = gql`
  type Robot {
    name: String!
    status: String!
  }

  type Member {
    name: String!
    isLogged: Boolean!
  }

`;

export const resolvers = {
  Member: {
    isLogged: (...args) => {
      console.log('args', args); // THIS NEVER TRIGGERS SOMEHOW
      return true;
    }
  }
};
```

Query

```
const GET_IS_MEMBER_LOGGED = gql`
  query isMemberLogged {
    member @client {
      name
      isLogged
    }
  }
`;
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `export const resolvers = {
  member: {` - `member` lowercased ? ... and you need resolver for entire member

Comment: Hi xadm. Thanks for your help. Member is a type so it shouldn't be lovercased like in the case of Query resolvers. Can you, please, show me the example of the full member resolver? I thought I did in correctly

Answer (score 1):

You need to define result type of local queries:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  extend type Query {
    robot: Robot
    member: Member
  }
```

... and **resolver for your query - not type** (as you decorated entire query as local)... but **you have to return typed data**:

```
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    member: (...args) => {
      console.log('args', args); 
      return {
        __typename: 'Member',
        name: 'some name', // read from cache
        isLogged: true // function result
      };
    }
  }
};
```

You should also use `__typename` for cache writes.

### update

assuming you have a Memeber in cache ... you can:

```
// read (initialized with permanent) data:
const memberData = cache.readQuery(....
// f.e. it should have `__typename` and 'name`
// ... and 'decorate' it with derived properites
memberData.age = currentYear - memberData.birthYear;
memberData.isLogged = someFuncReturningBool();
return memberData; // Member type shaped object
```

It's about shape/data organization - typed (return type shaped object with defined properties) or simple (return all properties separately) or mixed, f.e. (some global app state)

```
const GET_IS_MEMBER_LOGGED = gql`
  query profileViewData {
    member @client {
      name
      isLogged
    }
    isProfilePanelOpen @client
    termsAccepted @client
  }
`;
```

Comment: what if I want to have a predefined initial Member model in the cache and I want to have a few _computed fields_ that shouldn't be presented in the cache but should be presented by resolvers that toake some values from member cache and generate these new fields? eg. fullName. How to achieve it? Should I have a member Query resolver if I have it in the cache already and all that I want is just a few additional 'computed' fields ?

Comment: Thank you xadm. It's a cool solution and it looks like it might work. But again, is there existing a way to create resolvers for such fields without executing the Query -> Member resolver? I'd like to keep these things clean and separated. for ex: use Query resolver for non-existing objects in the initial cache (generated on the fly) and resolvers with non-existing fields for the **existing** objects in the initial cache.

Comment: "By default, @client based fields leverage the cache in the exact same manner as remote fields. After a local resolver is run, its result is cached alongside any remote results. " - cached data must be typed, there is no 'non-existing fields' case (additional fields are ignored on cache write - like on remote server, resolver can return more but response is filtered to type/request shape) ... however you can use customJSON type (read docs) to store (and read) anything in some object.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution. Maybe this info will be useful for someone.
If we want to omit the Query Resolver + Field resolvers and we want to have the only Field resolver we need to use **@client(always: true)**.

**The *in deep* explanation**

In general, there is a problem with how the Apollo client works with Cache.
By default, it caches the response, and next time it'll fetch the cached result from the cache (eg. [optimistic UI](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/optimistic-ui/)). This behavior is the same even in the case of the Client.


It means when we have the initial model in cache Apollo will fetch in from the cache and ignores the resolvers, even if we pass the @client directive.
To solve this problem and let Apollo know that we need to use Local resolvers EVEN if we have a cached object, we need to use **@client(always: true)** for the preferred field or the whole object. I made an example below.


P.S. Unfortunately I didn't find how to force Apollo to work with non-existing field so if we want to have some resolver for a specific field, we still need to define the initial field value it the initial Cached Model to let the Apollo know about this field. After that, Apollo will use resolver for it to generate some high-calculated output for this particular field, thanks to **@client(always: true)**. 
In general, it's ok, because we should know what kind of dynamic field we'll have in our model.

Apollo client

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

import { resolvers, typeDefs } from './resolvers';
import { initCache } from './init-cache';

export default function createApolloClient(initialState, ctx) {
  // The `ctx` (NextPageContext) will only be present on the server.
  // use it to extract auth headers (ctx.req) or similar.
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: Boolean(ctx),
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/cixmkt2ul01q00122mksg82pn', // Server URL (must be absolute)
      credentials: 'include', // Additional fetch() options like `credentials` or `headers`
      fetch,
    }),
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    connectToDevTools: true,
    cache: initCache({
                     author: {
                     __typename: 'Author',
                     posts: 0,
                     name: '' // NEED TO SET AN INITIAL VALUE
                     }
     })
  }
```

Types & resolvers (resolvers.js)

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { print  } from 'graphql';

export const typeDefs = gql`
  type Author {
    posts: Int!
    name: String
  }

`;


export const resolvers = {
  Author: {
    name(author) {
      console.log('Author name resolver', author). // WORKS
      return 'NAME';
    },
  },

};
```

Query

```
const GET_AUTHOR = gql`
  query getAuthor {
    author {
      posts
      name @client(always: true)
    }
  }
`;
```